# How to make a wrapper vue component in Solara

Tags: vue.js, solara

I want to create a new vuejs component in Solara that will wrap children.
I was hoping the children components will render in the default slot of the component, but this did not happen.
How can you make the `children` components to render inside the vue component?

Example of (not working) code:

```js
<template>
  <div style="background:red; padding:15px">
    I was expecting children to be below:<br>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default { } 
</script>
```

```py
@solara.component_vue("wrapper-cont.vue")
def WrapperCont():
    pass
```

```
@solara.component
def Page():
  with WrapperCont():
     solara.MarkDown("child 1")
     solara.MarkDown("child 2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slot mechanism of vuejs isn't used (yet) by Solara.

Instead you need to pass `children` to your component and render them in a loop using the `jupyter-widget` component.

Like so:

```js
<template>
  <div style="background:red; padding:15px">
    Children will appear below:<br>
    <jupyter-widget v-for="child in children" :key="child" :widget="child"></jupyter-widget>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default { } 
</script>
```

```py
@solara.component_vue("wrapper-cont.vue")
def WrapperCont(children=[]):   # Note passing children as property
    pass
```

Note: The solution is currently not documented, so it might be internal API. It was found in Solara source code `download.vue`, so if it becomes obsolete I suggest to look there for updated solution (and update this answer).

Comment: This is indeed the way to do it. It is indeed not directly documented on solara, but it is in ipyvuetify https://ipyvuetify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/template_usage.html#embed-ipywidgets so this is a supported/stable feature.